# how to configure nginx for all error handling when using with Django and Gunicorn?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

If I am using Nginx, Django, and Gunicorn, how to use Nginx to handle all errors with static contents, e.g. 404, etc?

Reason) If for some reasons, Django or Gunicorn crashes (and either of them won't come back up), normally error content handled by Django cannot be served anymore, how to configure nginx to handle the error properly?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If Django fails then nginx will return a 502 error, which is the correct response. What do you want it to do?

Comment: If there any way to let nginx to handle errors, e.g. 404, 400, etc, as fallback?

Comment: How would nginx know whether to serve a 404 unless Django is working?

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog:

[Setting up Django with Nginx, Gunicorn, virtualenv, supervisor and PostgreSQL](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)

Has great content for setting up Django on production using **gunicorn & nginx**. Also covers setting up *static* and *media* files.

Might help :)